# How would you word this function differently?

Tags: c++

My calculations are incorrect in the sense that my program thinks, for example, that 2022 is a leap year and 2024 is not. How do I fix this, please?? I've tried changing the bool statement but nothing seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>

int leapYear(int year)
{
    return (((year % 400) == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0)&& !(year % 100 == 0)));
}
// extracted
}
```

Comment: Your `leapYear` function returns `true` as you are returning either `28` or `29`, instead of an integer. Also look up operator precedence

Comment: I'll definitely look it up. but I must say that I am quite confused as to what you mean by what it is returning.

Comment: When you call your leap year function, you ignore it's return value. Also, you should not use global variables, makes the code more difficult to follow and more error prone. Further, the leap year function refers to a variable called y, which is not defined. Lastly, follow the logic of that function with values like 2022 and 2024.

Comment: Oh okay! I'd like to ask if "int month, day, year, start = 0" is a global variable that shouldn't be used?

Comment: @dreculaxi That's three global variable, yes. Call `printMonth` more than once in January and see what happens.

Comment: There is already a built-in library if you have C++20
https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/calendar-and-time-zone-in-c-20

Comment: By the way: this code doesn't compile, so it can't produce any results at all. It's impossible to tell which problems are real and which are a result of your posting the wrong code.

Comment: Oops! I must've messed with something - but it's compiling now! @molbdnilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in the leap Year function

```
return (((year % 400) == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0)&& !(year % 100 == 0)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just answer the title

---

with c++20 you can use [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year/is_leap) to do it

```
std::chrono::year{y}.is_leap()
```

---

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/MGPqMWWWG)